# Construye una función que dado un arreglo de números devuelva un arreglo del doble de cada elemento

Tags: javascript

Buen dia , necesito solucionar ese ejercicio de javascript , donde me que multiplique por el mismo valor del arreglo , algo así como una potencia , se debe resolver con Funciones de orden superior

```
var sumaDoble;
var arreglo1 = [1,2,3,4,5];

sumaDoble = arreglo1.filter(x => {
return 
});
```

en el return es donde debo hacer la operación matematica el resultado debe ser este

```
[2,4,6,8,10]
```

Comment: ¿Usas el método filter por alguna razón en particular?

Comment: No, puesto a que estoy aprendiendo funciones de orden superior , y esos temas fue los que vimos antes de estos ejercicios , pensaba que con el metodo filter() se podría llegar a solucionar

Comment: ¿Y qué has intentado? Parece que buscas que alguien resuelva el ejercicio por ti.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `filter`, sirve (como su nombre indica) para filtrar los datos de un array (seleccionar los que cumplan cierta condición). Para trabajar con esos datos mejor usa el método `forEach`.
Por otra parte, parece que piden devolver un array, no modificar un array ya existente.
Una solución fácil, es crear un array vació, llenarlo con el doble de los valores del array dado, y devolverlo.

```js
var array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];

function sumaDoble(entrada)
{
  var respuesta=[];
  entrada.forEach(x => respuesta.push(x*2));
  return respuesta;
}
console.log(sumaDoble(array1));
```

Ten en cuenta que este ejemplo da por supuesto que el array dado es correcto.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, voy a ponerlo en práctica y valido para ver si así era la solución de el ejercicio, del mismo modo muchísimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo me es de gran ayuda

Answer (score 0):

investigando y dando otra solución a la pregunta se realizaría de la siguiente manera :

```
var sumaDoble;
var arreglo1 = [1,2,3,4,5];

sumaDoble = arreglo1.map(x => {
return x*2
});
```

Utilizamos .map() que crea un nuevo array e itera sobre cada valor del primer array , luego le decimos que por cada valor que hay en el primer arreglo x*2 así lo multiplica por el mismo valor